# Can't create a table due to Foreign key constraint, on ubuntu/trusty64 php5-mysql

Tags: mysql, ubuntu

I have moved my project from XAMP to VM->Vagrant->ubuntu/trusty64->Installed(php5-mysql mysql-server mysql-client)

Now when I try to create my DB and tables I get the following error.

**ERROR**
Can't create table `properties`, Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed. There is no index in the referenced table where the referenced columns appear as the first columns.

This is my first script so I am assuming there is some errors but it all worked fine when i used XAMP. I have been reading about engines that you use and character sets but I don't know much about it or how to edit it on in vagrant. Thanks for all the help Code is below.

**MySQL**

```
CREATE TABLE `usertypes`(
`id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`type` CHAR(15),
`permissions` CHAR(15),
PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
);

INSERT INTO `usertypes`(`type`,`permissions`) VALUES ("Administrator", '{"Admin":1}' ), ("Staff", '{"Staff":1}'), ("Basic", '{"Basic":1}'), ("Pro", '{"Pro":1}'), ("Business", '{"Business":1}');

CREATE TABLE `users` (
`id` INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
`username` VARCHAR (25) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
`password` VARCHAR (60) NOT NULL,
`usertype` INT NOT NULL DEFAULT 3,
`email` varchar(40) NOT NULL,
`authentication` varchar(32) NOT NULL,
`active` smallint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
`newsletter` INT NOT NULL,
`banned` SMALLINT NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
`user_since` DATE NOT NULL,
`listings` INT DEFAULT 0,
CONSTRAINT fk_usertype FOREIGN KEY (`usertype`) REFERENCES usertypes(`id`),
UNIQUE KEY `users` (`username`,`email`)
);

CREATE TABLE `personal` (
`id` INT PRIMARY KEY,
`first_name` VARCHAR (15) NULL,
`last_name` VARCHAR (15) NULL,
`mobile_phone` CHAR(10) NULL,
`city` CHAR(25) NULL,
`address` VARCHAR (100) NULL,
`postal_code` VARCHAR(6) NULL,
CONSTRAINT fk_personal FOREIGN KEY (`id`)
REFERENCES users(`id`)
);

/* Create Properties table */
CREATE TABLE `propertytypes`(
`id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`type` CHAR(10),
PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
);

INSERT INTO `propertytypes`(`type`) VALUES ("house"), ("duplex"), ("apartment"), ("townhouse"), ("4 plex"),("6 plex"), ("room"), ("commercial"), ("gathering halls");

CREATE TABLE `utilities`(
`id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`options` CHAR(10),
PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
);

INSERT INTO `utilities`(`options`) VALUES ("None"),("Heat"), ("Electricity"), ("Water"), ("TV"), ("Internet");

CREATE TABLE `features`(
`id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`options` CHAR(10),
PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
);

INSERT INTO `features`(`options`) VALUES ("Coin Laundry"), ("Own Laundry"), ("Jetted Tub / Jacuzzi"), ("Gym"), ("Pool"), ("Security"), ("Balcony"), ("Elevator"), ("Hardwood Floors"), ("Fenced Backyard"), ("Dishwasher"), ("Air Conditioning"), ("Laminate Floors"), ("Fire Pit"), ("Fireplace"), ("Wheelchair Access"), ("Storage Lockers");

CREATE TABLE `properties` (
 `id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `owner` INT NOT NULL,
 `propertytype` INT NOT NULL,
 `address` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
 `postalcode` varchar(8) NOT NULL,
 `beds` INT(10),
 `baths` INT(10),
 `sqf` DECIMAL (6,2),
 `price` DECIMAL (6,2),
 `images` varchar(32),
 `listed` smallint(1) DEFAULT 2,
 `pets` smallint(1) DEFAULT 2,
 `kids` smallint(1) DEFAULT 2,
 `adults` smallint(1) DEFAULT 2,
 `utilities` INT NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
 `features` INT NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
 `parking` smallint(1) DEFAULT 2,
 `smokers` smallint(1) DEFAULT 2,
 `deposit` smallint(1) DEFAULT 0,
 `description` TEXT NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
CONSTRAINT fk_users FOREIGN KEY (`owner`)
REFERENCES users(`id`),
CONSTRAINT fk_propertytypes FOREIGN KEY (`propertytype`)
REFERENCES propertytypes(`id`),
CONSTRAINT fk_utilities FOREIGN KEY (`utilities`)
REFERENCES utilities(`options`),
CONSTRAINT fk_features FOREIGN KEY (`features`)
REFERENCES features(`options`)
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This runs all the way thru

Look for the lines that say CHANGE MADE

Columns were not being specified correctly. Plus there were 2 columns that had truncates during insert.

```
create schema ff; -- create a new db
use ff; -- now use that db

CREATE TABLE `usertypes`(
`id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`type` CHAR(15),
`permissions` CHAR(15),
PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
);

INSERT INTO `usertypes`(`type`,`permissions`) VALUES ("Administrator", '{"Admin":1}' ), ("Staff", '{"Staff":1}'), ("Basic", '{"Basic":1}'), ("Pro", '{"Pro":1}'), ("Business", '{"Business":1}');

CREATE TABLE `users` (
`id` INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
`username` VARCHAR (25) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
`password` VARCHAR (60) NOT NULL,
`usertype` INT NOT NULL DEFAULT 3,
`email` varchar(40) NOT NULL,
`authentication` varchar(32) NOT NULL,
`active` smallint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
`newsletter` INT NOT NULL,
`banned` SMALLINT NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
`user_since` DATE NOT NULL,
`listings` INT DEFAULT 0,
CONSTRAINT fk_usertype FOREIGN KEY (`usertype`) REFERENCES usertypes(`id`),
UNIQUE KEY `users` (`username`,`email`)
);

CREATE TABLE `personal` (
`id` INT PRIMARY KEY,
`first_name` VARCHAR (15) NULL,
`last_name` VARCHAR (15) NULL,
`mobile_phone` CHAR(10) NULL,
`city` CHAR(25) NULL,
`address` VARCHAR (100) NULL,
`postal_code` VARCHAR(6) NULL,
CONSTRAINT fk_personal FOREIGN KEY (`id`)
REFERENCES users(`id`)
);

/* Create Properties table */
-- drop table propertytypes;
CREATE TABLE `propertytypes`(
`id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`type` CHAR(40), -- CHANGE MADE ************************
PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
);

INSERT INTO `propertytypes`(`type`) VALUES ("house"), ("duplex"), ("apartment"), ("townhouse"), ("4 plex"),("6 plex"), ("room"), ("commercial"), ("gathering halls");

-- drop table utilities;
CREATE TABLE `utilities`(
`id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`options` CHAR(40), -- CHANGE MADE ************************
PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
);

INSERT INTO `utilities`(`options`) VALUES ("None"),("Heat"), ("Electricity"), ("Water"), ("TV"), ("Internet");

CREATE TABLE `features`(
`id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`options` CHAR(40), -- CHANGE MADE ************************
PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
);

INSERT INTO `features`(`options`) VALUES ("Coin Laundry"), ("Own Laundry"), ("Jetted Tub / Jacuzzi"), ("Gym"), ("Pool"), ("Security"), ("Balcony"), ("Elevator"), ("Hardwood Floors"), ("Fenced Backyard"), ("Dishwasher"), ("Air Conditioning"), ("Laminate Floors"), ("Fire Pit"), ("Fireplace"), ("Wheelchair Access"), ("Storage Lockers");

CREATE TABLE `properties` (
 `id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `owner` INT NOT NULL,
 `propertytype` INT NOT NULL,
 `address` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
 `postalcode` varchar(8) NOT NULL,
 `beds` INT(10),
 `baths` INT(10),
 `sqf` DECIMAL (6,2),
 `price` DECIMAL (6,2),
 `images` varchar(32),
 `listed` smallint(1) DEFAULT 2,
 `pets` smallint(1) DEFAULT 2,
 `kids` smallint(1) DEFAULT 2,
 `adults` smallint(1) DEFAULT 2,
 `utilities` INT NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
 `features` INT NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
 `parking` smallint(1) DEFAULT 2,
 `smokers` smallint(1) DEFAULT 2,
 `deposit` smallint(1) DEFAULT 0,
 `description` TEXT NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`),

CONSTRAINT fk_users FOREIGN KEY (`owner`)
REFERENCES users(`id`),

CONSTRAINT fk_propertytypes FOREIGN KEY (`propertytype`)
REFERENCES propertytypes(`id`),

CONSTRAINT fk_utilities FOREIGN KEY (`utilities`)
REFERENCES utilities(`id`), -- CHANGE MADE ************************

CONSTRAINT fk_features FOREIGN KEY (`features`)
REFERENCES features(`id`) -- CHANGE MADE ************************
);

drop schema ff; -- drop test db (cleanup)
```

Also, consider removing the `DEFAULT 0` if they would conflict with an FK constraint that starts at 1 and up. I frankly don't see the point of it.

From the mysql Manual Page entitled [Using FOREIGN KEY Constraints](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html)

> Corresponding columns in the foreign key and the referenced key must
>   have similar data types. The size and sign of integer types must be
>   the same. The length of string types need not be the same. For
>   nonbinary (character) string columns, the character set and collation
>   must be the same.

and

> MySQL requires indexes on foreign keys and referenced keys so that
>   foreign key checks can be fast and not require a table scan. In the
>   referencing table, there must be an index where the foreign key
>   columns are listed as the first columns in the same order. Such an
>   index is created on the referencing table automatically if it does not
>   exist. This index might be silently dropped later, if you create
>   another index that can be used to enforce the foreign key constraint.
>   index_name, if given, is used as described previously.

Comment: Thank you that makes sense I understand it, however could you tell me why would it work in my other environment and not this one? Thanks

Comment: well the bottom two FK's were are columns with mismatched / unindexec columns for the referenced table. The last table is the *referencing* table. It references 4 *referenced* tables. See bottom of question where I added a link and some stuff from the manual page.

Comment: As for your other system, who knows. I know nothing about it.

Comment: Thank you very much!.. Appreciate the help